# How to use dplyr to look up a calculated value in the same column one row above?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

In the reproducible code below, with dplyr I'm trying to create a dataframe column `nameCntSpltGrp` that, by Excel analogy, looks at its own calculated value in the row above in deriving the value for the current cell. However the calculation for that column doesn't work in the reproducible code and is commented out. How can I fix this, so each cell in that `nameCntSpltGrp` column looks at the calculated value one row above?

Illustrated below is how the calculation correctly works in XLS for `nameCntSpltGrp` :

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","T","R","N","N"),
    Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

myDataFill <- myData %>%
  group_by(Name, Group) %>% 
    mutate(nameCnt = row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(subGrpRank = ifelse(Group > 0,row_number(),0))%>% 
    mutate(nameCntSplt = ifelse(subGrpRank == 1, nameCnt,0)) %>% 
  ungroup() # %>%
  
  # mutate(nameCntSpltGrp = ifelse(nameCntSplt > 0, nameCntSplt,
  #                                  ifelse(Name == lag(Name),lag(nameCntSpltGrp),0)))

myDataFill
print.data.frame(myDataFill)
```

Comment: Perhaps `dplyr`'s `lag` function inside of the mutate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the closest I come to your excel example, I hope it helps:

```
myDataFill <- myData %>%
  group_by(Name, Group) %>% 
  mutate(nameCnt = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(subGrpRank = ifelse(Group > 0,row_number(),0))%>% 
  mutate(nameCntSplt = ifelse(subGrpRank == 1, nameCnt,0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(nameCntSpltGrp = nameCntSplt) %>% 
  mutate(nameCntSpltGrp = ifelse(nameCntSplt > 0, 
                                 nameCntSplt,
                                 ifelse(Group == lag(Group), 
                                       lag(nameCntSpltGrp), 0)))
```

Comment: Have you successfully run this? I tried and it doesn't work, it crashes when running that last `mutate()`

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the closing brackets, the code is correct now.